# Is the function $Z(t,q)$ progressively measurable?

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes

The excercise is taken from Stroock and Varadhan Multidimensional diffusion processes chap 1 page 44 is the following
[image]

To the first part, I reasoned as follows:

Consider the function $F(q_1,q_3) = 1_{A}(q_1) 1_{B}(q_3)$ for $A \in \mathcal{F}_1$ and $B \in \mathcal{F}_3$

Then define
$$|G|(q_1,q_2): = \int F(q_1,q_3) \, |\mu|(q_2,\, dq_3) = 1_{A}(q_1) |\mu(q_2,B)|\\
G(q_1,q_2): = \int F(q_1,q_3) \, \mu(q_2,\, dq_3) = 1_{A}(q_1) \mu(q_2,B) $$

Since $\mu(q_2,\cdot)$ is a signed measure, $|\mu(q_2,B)|< \infty$ and since $q_2 \mapsto \mu(q_2,B)$ is $\mathcal{F}_2$ measurable $|G|(q_1,q_2)$ is $\mathcal{F}_1\otimes \mathcal{F}_2$ measurable.

The same is true for simple functions $F(q_1,q_3) = \sum_{i,j=1}^K \alpha_{i,j} 1_{A_i}(q_1)1_{B_j}(q_3)$

Now any positive measurable fuction $F(q_1,q_3)$ is the increasing limit of simple functions $F_n$. Notice that $|G|_n \leq |G|_{n+1}$ once $F_n \leq F_{n+1}$

The set $N^c = \{(q_1,q_2) \mid \lim_n |G|_n(q_1,q_2) = \infty\} = \cap_m \cup_n \{(q_1,q_2) \mid  |G|_n(q_1,q_2) > m\}$ is a measurable set (in $\mathcal{F}_1\otimes \mathcal{F}_2$)

In $N$ the function $G(q_1,q_2) = \lim_n G_n(q_1,q_2)$ is $\mathcal{F}_1\otimes \mathcal{F}_2$ measurable

Since any Measurable function can be splited in its positive part and negative part $F = F^+ - F^{-}$ we concluded the first part of the exercise.

---

**Now comes the hard part**

---

I am not sure how to deal with $\theta(s,q)$ nor with $\eta(s,q)$

I tried to consider $F((s,q), t) = 1_{[0,t]}(s) \theta(s,q)$ and $\mu((s,q), t) = \eta(s\wedge t, q)$. Note that $\mu$ is a signed measure satisfying the conditions of the first part

In this case $E_1 = E_2 = [0,\infty) \times \Omega$ and $\mathcal{F}_1 = \mathcal{F}_2 = \text{Prog}$ the sigma algebra of progressively measurable proccesses and $\mathcal{F}_3 = \mathcal{B}[0,\infty)$

In this case we obtain

$G((t,q), (t,q)) = \int_0^t \theta(s,q)\eta( ds, q) $ if $\int_0^t \theta(s,q)|\eta|( ds, q) $ as a $\mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_1$ measurable function. This means that $Z(t,q) = G((t,q), (t,q))$ is a $\mathcal{F}_1$ measurable function, that is a progressively measurable function.

Is this argument correct?